# Fugace ou fugitif

Tags: choix-de-mot, sens, adjectifs

Je voudrais savoir quelle est la différence entre fugace et fugitif.
S'appliquant à un astre.
Une idée ? Évidemment je m'intéresse à des avis qu'on ne trouve pas dans le dictionnaire.

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui te gêne dans les avis qu'on trouve dans les dictionnaires ?

Comment: Rien, je l'ai déjà fait moi-même.

Comment: Et qu'est-ce qui leur manque pour que tu poses la question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

À mon avis *fugace* est orienté vers l'observateur: difficile à percevoir à cause de ses capacités sensorielles, tandis que *fugitif* implique un plus grand dynamisme de la part de l'observé : c'est la chose observée qui tente de manière active d’échapper à l'observation.

Comment: C'est une intuition de locuteur natif ou tu as des sources ?

Comment: Locuteur natif, merci pour les accents. La difference est au niveau poetique vu le champ lexical des mots concernes, donc affaire de nuance. Le fait que fugitif soit aussi un nom, qqn qui fuit, cree sans doute cette association dans l'esprit du lecteur. Le dictionnaire confirme: le sens qui correspond a 'fugitif' n'est plus en usage: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fugace . Donc fugitif a un sens en plus.